# Restart Spring Boot when input text file changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Extending the question here:

[Reading data from file at start to use in controller in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424524/reading-data-from-file-at-start-to-use-in-controller-in-spring-boot)

I want my spring boot application restart in production when the input file changes. I will start the app with something like this

```
java -jar application.jar [filename]
```

And when I modify the input text file, the app must be restarted and read the file again. How can I do it? I am asking how to watch file changes and trigger restart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically restart Spring Boot application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117308/programmatically-restart-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution using shell script**

I will suggest to monitor your input file using file watchers, and if any file change detected, you can restart your app using shell scripts.

You didn't provided platform information.

> If your production is on Linux then you can use [watch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) to monitor
>   changes in your input file.

**Solution using Java**

If you want to detect the file change in Java, you could use FileWatcher,

```
final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
System.out.println(path);
try{
    final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    final WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
    while (true) {
        final WatchKey wk = watchService.take();
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
            //we only register "ENTRY_MODIFY" so the context is always a Path.
            final Path changed = (Path) event.context();
            System.out.println(changed);
            if (changed.endsWith("myFile.txt")) {
                System.out.println("My file has changed");
            }
        }
        // reset the key
        boolean valid = wk.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            System.out.println("Key has been unregisterede");
        }
    }
}
```

Now to restart your app from within java, you have to start your application from within your main method.

Create a separate thread that will monitor your input file, and launch your app in a separate thread.

Whenever you detect any change in your input file, interrupt or kill the app thread, and re launch your application in a new thread.

Comment: yes it is ubuntu 16.04 but I must do it inside the program itself

Comment: In java you can detect file changes using FileWatcher API